# Difference in MySQL JOIN vs LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, left-join, inner-join

I have this cross-database query...

```
SELECT
            `DM_Server`.`Jobs`.*,
            `DM_Server`.servers.Description AS server,
            digital_inventory.params,
            products.products_id,
            products.products_pdfupload,
            customers.customers_firstname,
            customers.customers_lastname
        FROM `DM_Server`.`Jobs`
        INNER JOIN `DM_Server`.servers ON servers.ServerID = Jobs.Jobs_ServerID
        JOIN `cpod_live`.`digital_inventory` ON digital_inventory.jobname = Jobs.Jobs_Name
        JOIN `cpod_live`.`products` ON products.products_pdfupload = CONCAT(digital_inventory.jobname, ".pdf")
        JOIN `cpod_live`.`customers` ON customers.customers_id = products.cID
        ORDER BY `DM_Server`.`Jobs`.Jobs_StartTime DESC LIMIT 50
```

it runs fine until I make them `LEFT JOIN`s.  I thought that by not specifying a type of join it was assumed to be a `LEFT JOIN`.  Is this not the case?

Answer (score 201, accepted):

> I thought that by not specifying a type of join it was assumed to be a LEFT JOIN. Is this not the case?

No, the default join is an INNER JOIN.

Here is [a visual explanation of SQL joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html).

**Inner join**

[image]

**Left join**

[image]

Comment: By Cross-database the TS probably means that his query uses tables from multiple databases.

Comment: Is there a big reason why a `LEFT JOIN` would be so much slower than an `INNER JOIN` ?

Comment: @Webnet: It could potentially return more rows. That could, in some situations, cause it to be slower.

Answer (score 14):

No.  When a type isn't specified, an `INNER JOIN` is used. To read up on differences; [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29)

Answer (score 11):

I believe the default is `INNER JOIN` if you just specify `JOIN`.

Answer (score 9):

> If you just mentioned JOIN in query by default it will be considered
>   as a INNER JOIN.

Left join:Left join will take all the elements from Left table and only matching records from the Right table as Follows.
example:

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name1 #(Left table)
LEFT JOIN table_name2 #(Right table)
ON table_name1.column_name=table_name2.column_name
```

Hope this helps.