# Difficulty with join 3 tables in a query in php

Tags: php, sql, join, forum

My database has 3 tables i wish to access in the select query but I cannot seem to get it to work. Selecting from 2 tables works fine so I know everything else is working apart from my code for selecting from 3 tables. My database has been created on PHPmyadmin

The Tables are as follows:

forum_replies

- reply_id
- topic_id
- user_id
- reply_text
- reply date

forum_topics

- topic_id
- category_id
- user_id
- topic_title
- topic_description
- topic_date

users

- user_id
- username

This is the code I have tried to use and shows the fields I wish to select:

```
    $queryreply = "SELECT forum_replies.reply_id, forum_replies.topic_id, forum_replies.user_id,
                       forum_replies.reply_text, forum_replies.reply_date, users.user_id, users.username
                       forum_topics.topic_id,forum_topics.topic_title, forum_topics.topic_date
                       FROM forum_replies
                       JOIN forum_topics
                       ON forum_replies.topic_id = forum_topics.topic_id
                       JOIN users
                       ON forum_replies.user_id = users.user_id

                       ";


        $result = mysql_query($queryreply) or die (mysql_error());
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

Example in code would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: *cannot seem to get it to work*... what is your expected result? also, stop using deprecated `mysql_*` functions; use PDO / MySQLi instead. last, make good use of table alias.

Comment: Yeah I understand it's deprecated but my university I'm studying at has told me to do so. I won't use in the future. I am at this moment just trying to echo out the $row to show all the replies to a topic on my forum website. With user details showing who posted them

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.topic_id,forum_topics.topic_title, forum_topics.topic_date FROM forum_' at line 3

Comment: You are missing a comma `,` between `users.username forum_topics.topic_id`

Comment: Dam, thanks you so much. the comma was the error. I have literally been working straight for 24 hours and need some fresh eyes to look over my code. Thank all you guys for your help! Feel silly now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this query:

```
SELECT a.reply_text, a.reply_date, b.topic_title, c.username
FROM forum_replies a
LEFT JOIN forum_topics b ON a.topic_id=b.topic_id
LEFT JOIN users c ON a.user_id=c.user_id
// apply WHERE, ORDER, GROUP if needed
```

Apart from syntax errors, you should use `LEFT JOIN` and table alias in your case.

---

To show also the topic creator's username, you can adjust the query to the following:

```
SELECT a.reply_text, a.reply_date, b.topic_title, c.username AS reply_user, (SELECT username FROM users WHERE user_id=b.user_id) AS topic_creator
FROM forum_replies a
LEFT JOIN forum_topics b ON a.topic_id=b.topic_id
LEFT JOIN users c ON a.user_id=c.user_id
// apply WHERE, ORDER, GROUP if needed
```

Comment: ironically you have a syntax error in `a,reply_text`

Comment: Thanks for your help, may I ask why left join instead of join?

Comment: You can refer to this: [Difference between JOIN (default is INNER JOIN) and LEFT JOIN](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9770366/difference-in-mysql-join-vs-left-join). In your case, topic replies are the key information you want to obtain. If you use INNER JOIN, if topic / user is missing somehow, the replies won't be shown.

Comment: Thanks I understand it now, I was wondering if you could help me with this new problem i'm facing.  My forum page currently shows the forum title and  all the replies to that specific forum (As well as the usernames of those who have replied) but i am also trying to show the username of the person who created the forum title, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: updated the answer. You can perform a sub-query to find out the topic creator

Comment: I've never used a sub-query before, I didn't want to just ask you to do it for me so have spent the last hour trying to put something together but cannot  understand any of it. Could you please explain to me how I would retrieve username of topic creator through topic id referenced in forum_replies. Any help would be appreciated, I've updated the answer

Comment: As the selected topic creator is now named as `topic_creator` from the SQL, you can retrieve it by `$row['topic_creator']`. Have fun with MySQL!

Comment: Thank you so much, I'm new to coding so thank you for putting up with me,  I really appreciate it.

Comment: this is really not fair to open a new question and asking the same again :-( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29814618/select-fields-using-foreign-keys-in-relational-table

Answer (score 0):

You miss the `,` after `users.username`..

```
SELECT forum_replies.reply_id, forum_replies.topic_id, forum_replies.user_id,
forum_replies.reply_text, forum_replies.reply_date, users.user_id, users.username,
 forum_topics.topic_id,forum_topics.topic_title, forum_topics.topic_date
```

Comment: Thanks you for your help, seems to be working for now!