# sql query is behaving strange

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query

```
select c.CommentId
,c.CommentText
, c.CommenterId
, c.CommentDate
, u.first_name
, u.last_name
, i.ImageName
, i.Format 
from comment c 
join users u 
  on  c.CommenterId = u.user_id 
join user_profile_image i 
  on u.user_id = i.UserId 
where PostId = 76 
 order 
  by CommentDate desc 
limit 10
```

This query returns empty results when i.ImageName field is empty in the table. I want to return the row if the ImageName field is emty. How should I do this?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would you call a field `user_id` in one table but `userid` in another?

Comment: @GordonLinoff what do you mean? I used some ready made login system that used the underscore but I personally don't like this .. If this answers your curiosity?

Comment: FWIW, I prefer it with the underscore. It prevents confusion of the Pen Island variety.

Comment: Pen Island variety??? :o

Comment: penisland - underscores would help make that less embarrassing ;) pen_island.

Comment: @whatever . . . I don't have really strong opinions about the underscore (personally, I would leave it out).  I do have strong opinions about consistency.

Comment: @GordonLinoff yes that is what i prefer too...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JOIN` defaults to `INNER JOIN` for MySQL - try changing

`join user_profile_image i`

to

`LEFT join user_profile_image i`

The accepted answer here has a good visual explanation: [Difference in MySQL JOIN vs LEFT JOIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9770366/difference-in-mysql-join-vs-left-join)

Comment: Right now I am either too much tired or I am stupid.. I had no clue what to do... hhh thanks..

Answer (score 2):

To include the rows when the ImageName field is empty, use `LEFT JOIN`, like this:

```
SELECT c.CommentId,c.CommentText, c.CommenterId, c.CommentDate, u.first_name,
u.last_name,i.ImageName,i.Format
FROM comment c 
INNER JOIN users u ON c.CommenterId=u.user_id 
LEFT JOIN user_profile_image i ON u.user_id=i.UserId
WHERE PostId = 76
ORDER BY CommentDate DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue isn't exactly that `i.ImageName` is *empty*.  The issue is that there is no image associated with the user.  The `join` doesn't find an image, and without a match, the user isn't returned.

The solution is to use `left join`.  My inclination is to write the query entirely with `left join`:

```
select c.CommentId, c.CommentText, c.CommenterId, c.CommentDate,
       u.first_name, u.last_name,
       i.ImageName, i.Format
from comment c left join
     users u
     on c.CommenterId = u.user_id left join
     user_profile_image i
     on u.user_id = i.UserId
where PostId = 76
order by c.CommentDate desc
limit 10;
```

Note:  This assumes that `PostId` is in the `comment` table, which seems reasonable given the table names.