# MySQL - joined table query is null which makes the whole query null

Tags: mysql

I have the following MySQL query:

```
SELECT u.id, u.ap, q.quests
FROM users u
JOIN(              
  SELECT count(quest) as 'quests', user
  FROM active_quests
  WHERE user = 143
) q
ON u.id = q.user
WHERE u.id = 143
```

The problem I am running into is that sometimes the joined query from the `active_quests` table will be `NULL` because there will be no entry for that particular user. But this is causing the whole query to become `NULL`.

The user will always have an `ap` value, but not always a `quests` value.

I wanted to do something like `SELECT u.id, u.ap, IFNULL(q.quests, 0)`, but it doesn't work.

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Use LEFT JOJN  instead of join .  Only join will imply inner join .
[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9770366/difference-in-mysql-join-vs-left-join)