# I want to fetch multidimensional array in my table

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

[image: My table]

[image: My Post array]

How do i fetch multidimensional array data in my table. As per in my image foodname, quantity, price should be fetch in my table.

Comment: HTML or MySQL table? I don't understand the question.

Comment: Firstly you need to tell us about the table is it a `HTML` table or a table in a data base. Then you need to add your code in code tags not as an image because no one will be able to copy paste and give it try.

Comment: This is post array comes from add to cart page to send email page.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assuming that you have the relationships set up in here. 
Basically you would have on the food table: `quatity_id` and `price_id`. 
Having the relationships we just need to do a `join`:

```
select * from `food_table` where `food` = `Super man's soupe` join `quantity_table` where `food_table.quantity_id` = `food_table.id` join `price` where `food_table.price_id` = `food_table.id`
```

A `join` assumes that you have all the data otherwise it will throw you an error. Let's suppose you have another food called `Batman's soup` but you wouldn't have the price because you know... Batman has a shit ton of money. You would receive an error because you were trying to `join` a column that does not exists. For cases like this we need to use `leftjoin`.

[Difference in MySQL JOIN vs LEFT JOIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9770366/difference-in-mysql-join-vs-left-join)

Comment: This table not fetched from mysql. This is just post array data from add to cart page to email send page. I just want to loop this array into my table.

Comment: @JPSenthilKumar You should add a little bit of code and be more specific. Have you tried anything?