# ORDER By in Codeigniter Model

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
    $query = ('SELECT tb_imam.*, tb_bidang.bidang
                 FROM tb_imam JOIN tb_bidang
                   ON tb_imam.bidang_id = tb_bidang.id
                WHERE tb_imam.status = "Pengerja"
            ');

    return $this->db->query($query)->result_array();
```

How do I add an order by using my code like this? beg for your help, thank you

Comment: Since you're using a raw SQL string anyway, just add it to the raw string e.g. `$query = ('SELECT tb_imam.*, tb_bidang.bidang
                 FROM tb_imam JOIN tb_bidang
                   ON tb_imam.bidang_id = tb_bidang.id
                WHERE tb_imam.status = "Pengerja" ORDER BY something
            ');`

Comment: Solved...!!  thank you verry much,,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are using raw query like mysql query, so you can directly add "order by" clause at the end of the "where" clause,

```
 $query = ('SELECT tb_imam.*, tb_bidang.bidang
             FROM tb_imam JOIN tb_bidang
               ON tb_imam.bidang_id = tb_bidang.id
            WHERE tb_imam.status = "Pengerja"
            ORDER BY column_name');

return $this->db->query($query)->result_array();
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `ORDER BY`

```
$query = "SELECT tb_imam.*, tb_bidang.bidang
         FROM tb_imam 
         JOIN tb_bidang ON tb_imam.bidang_id = tb_bidang.id
         WHERE tb_imam.status = 'Pengerja' 
         ORDER BY prefix.column_name";

return $this->db->query($query)->result_array();
```

[**`JOIN` !== `LEFT JOIN`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9770366/difference-in-mysql-join-vs-left-join)

Get used to [Query Builder Class](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db->select("tb_imam.*,tb_bidang.bidang");

$this->db->from("tb_imam");

$this->db->join("tb_bidang","tb_imam.bidang_id = tb_bidang.id");

$this->db->where("tb_imam.status","Pengerja");

$this->db->order_by("column_name");

$this->db->get()->result_array();
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.