# laravel query builder count relationship

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I am stuck with a query builder in laravel 8

```
DB::table('users')
    ->join('contracts', 'users.id', '=', 'contracts.user_id')
    ->join('roles', 'roles.id', '=', 'users.role_id')
    ->select('users.id', 'users.username', 'users.email', DB::raw('COUNT(contracts.user_id) as numberOfContracts'))
    ->groupBy('users.id')
    ->paginate(10);
```

i am getting only 80 of total entries .... and I have 103 users.

I want to display all the users with paginate of course..... and show for each user the role and how many contracts have.

What I did wrong ?

*** UPDATE ***

the tables are these:

users (id, username, email, role_id)

contracts (id, name, user_id)

roles (id, name)

*** update 2 ***

If run the eloquent

```
User::with('contracts', 'role')
->withCount('contracts')
->paginate(10);
```

it return all the 103 with count. But how to do it with query builder ?

Comment: If you did a straight query in MySQL `SELECT * FROM users GROUP BY users.id` How many rows are returned?  Could it be there are duplicate IDs?

Comment: Hi @Zak. 103 rows

Comment: Have you run the raw MySQL query with the JOIN statements?

Comment: No i have not run it

Comment: Try that, without knowing your tables, and what's in them .. I am guessing one of your JOIN statements is limiting the number returned.

Comment: i have updated the question with the structure of the tables

Comment: I would STLL run the query manually ..  So you have a better understanding of what's being returned.

Comment: It would look something like:  `SELECT a.id, a.username, a.email, COUNT(b.user_id) as numberOfContracts
FROM users a
JEFT JOIN contracts b ON 
a.id = b.user_id
LEFT JOIN roles c
ON c.id = a.role_id
GROUP BY a.id`

Comment: I am still guessing that unless EVERY user has at least one entry in "contracts" AND every user has at least one entry in "roles" -- That's your issue.

Comment: your query from up is ok....it return all 103 users and counts the contracts.

Comment: Good .. Try the original query with `LEFT JOINS`  --  `->leftJoin(`  That should account for the "empties"

Comment: it seems to work... The left join was the problem ????

Comment: So you want ```users``` who has ```contracts```` right ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were using straight `JOIN` (which equated to an `INNER JOIN` since that's what MySQL defaults to) in Laravel Query Builder.  It will not account for Empty contracts, or roles.  You need a `LEFT JOIN` to do this.

```
DB::table('users')
    ->leftJoin('contracts', 'users.id', '=', 'contracts.user_id')
    ->leftJoin('roles', 'roles.id', '=', 'users.role_id')
    ->select('users.id', 'users.username', 'users.email', DB::raw('COUNT(contracts.user_id) as numberOfContracts'))
    ->groupBy('users.id')
    ->paginate(10);
```

See This SO Question to see the difference in `JOINS` -- [Difference in MySQL JOIN vs LEFT JOIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9770366/difference-in-mysql-join-vs-left-join)

Comment: i didn't know that simple join don't count empty ....in my case contracts :-)